# How to define the application boot file in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

OK, the question might look a bit over discussed but unfortunately I couldn't find a good answer for myself.

How to define a boot file for my web application in `.htaccess` that will run every time a request to my website is made? `ZF` uses `application/index.php` to define all global variables like: `APPLICATION_ENV`, `include_path()` etc. `WordPress` does this to load the necessary theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want everything to be routed through `/boot.php`, then you'd do one of the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/boot\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /boot.php [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /boot.php [L]
```

You can pass additional parameters to the boot.php either through the `_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable or through the query string:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /boot.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But I'm not sure how good this is: I think there may be cases accounted for improperly.